# What is the original meaning of the augmentative "stock-"?

Tags: etymology, adjective, prefix

For several adjectives we can build an augmentative by adding the prefix *"stock-"*

> Gestern Nacht war es hier **stockfinster**.
>   **Stocksteif** bleib er stehen und bewegte sich nicht von der Stelle.
>   Hans Wurst ist ein **stockkonservativer** Politiker gewesen.
>   Peter stürzte **stockbesoffen** auf Nachbars Tulpen.

Only for *"stocksteif"* we can assume that it may be used figuratively for *"Stock"* (*stick*) but for other adjectives this meaning does not fit at all.

Do we know anything on an original meaning of *"stock-"* that would make its usage as augmentative sensible?

Comment: I'm founding the "Takkat for President of Posting Awesome Questions" Committee now. Go Takkat!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [Grimm Brothers](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB/?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GS47844) come to our aid again (albeit quite far down in the "stock"-entry)...
I was very intruiged by the questions, since I strongly felt that "stock-" is a very common intensifier that lends itself readily to new formations (Takkat brings a bunch of examples: *stockblind, stocksauer, stockdumm, stocknüchtern, stocktaub*...) denoting "fundamentally having the adjective's property", "the epitome of the adjective".
 I suspect that it somehow has to do with "stock" referring to "1) truncus, der in der erde stehen gebliebene stumpf eines baumes mitsamt den wurzeln. im gegensatz zum stamm [...]" (Grimm) - Makes me think of "foundation", "basis", "reduced to essentials" etc.

The Grimms do not go that far out on a limb, tough - they just show that the use as an intensifying prefix is nothing new:

> 8) auf dem vorigen ["7) stock als schelte"] beruht eine reiche möglichkeit verstärkender
>   zusammensetzungen, deren mehr gelegentliche bildungen im folgenden
>   durch eine auswahl von beispielen geschildert werden sollen.
>    a) in
>   verbindung mit völkernamen.
>   α) von einem ausländer, der in den
>   anschauungen seines landes völlig befangen ist, was sich für unseren
>   wortbegriff besonders darin äuszert, dasz er nur seine sprache
>   spricht. stockwelsch [...]
>   [...]
>   d) in den ansichten und oft vorurtheilen seines standes befangen.
>   α) stockaristokrat, m.: [...]
>   β) besonders zu erwähnen ist noch der vor andern am alten hängende stockbauer:[...]
>   γ) auch stockkaufmann, m.: [...]

Comment: Exactly - also makes me think of "stock" in the sense of concentrated broth (or "base" (!) for soup)... It doesn't seem very far fetched to draw a parallel: a concentrated broth or infusion with very pronounced taste on one hand, on the other an idea or characteristic that is very pronounced.

Answer (score 6):

Für *stocksteif* hast du recht. *Steif sein wie ein Stock* <sup>[(GRIMM)](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB/?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&hitlist=&patternlist=&lemid=GS48257)</sup>

Im Falle von *stockfinster* bezieht sich *stock* auf [*Stockhaus*](http://www.enzyklo.de/Begriff/Stockhaus)

> stockfinster, adj. überaus finster, so dasz man keine hand vor augen sehen kann; eigentlich so finster, wie es im stock (4 f) stockhaus, gefängnisz ist; stockfinster wie im tiefsten gefängnisz, [...] <sup>[(GRIMM)](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB/?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GS47990)</sup>

Wie dort aber angedeutet wird, verliert sich diese Herleitung allmählich im Jenseits und es gibt inzwischen auch Quellen, die meinen: *Man kann keinen Stock vor Augen sehen*.

Zu den anderen beiden kann ich leider keine Quellen bieten, aber zumindest bei *stockkonservativ* ist die Bedeutung *steif sein wie ein Stock* wieder denkbar. Man bleibt bei einer alten Ansicht, Einstellung, Haltung und geht nicht auf neue Dinge ein. Man ist also unflexibel, folglich *steif wie ein Stock*.

*Stockbesoffen* finde ich etwas kniffliger, aber eine Meinung, die ich gelesen habe, ist:

> *Man ist so besoffen, dass man am Stock gehen muss, um nicht umzufallen*

Finde ich tatsächlich noch sehr naheliegend, aber ob es stimmt? For sure, I don't know.

Comment: Made me take a closer look at the source, though - and I found the relevant bit - thanks! :)

Comment: `keinen Stock vor Augen sehen` klingt sehr gewollt für mich. `Die Hand nicht vor Augen sehen` ist gängig, aber handduster hat man nie gehört. Ob der Stock dem Besoffenen wirklich hilft? Vielleicht wird auch das verstockte Gehabe, das Besoffenen, wenn auch nicht allen, typisch ist, beschrieben? Bei Flüssigkeiten spricht man auch vom stocken, im Sinne von gerinnen - womögl. gibt es da eine Verbindung?

Comment: Ich weiß, es ist lange her, aber: Für das Stockhaus findet sich wieder eine naheliegende (amerikanisch-)englische Entsprechung: the stockade, eine Einfriedung oder eine Palisade, aber auch im Sinne eines Militärgefängnisses.