# Wo leitet sich das verstärkende Präfix "stink-" her?

Tags: etymology, adjective, prefix

Erst in [neuerer Zeit](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=stinknormal,stinkreich,stinksauer&year_start=1920&year_end=2008&corpus=8&smoothing=3) findet man das verstärkende Präfix *"[stink-](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/stink_)"* zu verschiedenen Adjektiven:

- stinksauer
- stinkreich
- stinknormal

*...und noch viele mehr.*

Ist etwas darüber bekannt, woher dieses Präfix stammt? Gibt es überhaupt einen (naheliegenden) Zusammenhang mit dem Verb *"[stinken](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/stinken)"*?

Comment: Stinkfaul gibt es offenbar [schon länger.](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=stinknormal%2Cstinkreich%2Cstinkfaul&year_start=1850&year_end=2008&corpus=8&smoothing=3) Vielleicht hat sich das "stink-" von diesem Begriff auf andere ausgeweitet. Bei "faul" passt das "stink-" ja: Wenn etwas fault, dann stinkt es in der Regel.

Comment: "Pecunia non olet." Stimmt. Aber wenn man soviel davon hat, dass es doch stinkt, muss man ziemlich viel davon haben und ist damit *stinkreich*

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Das Grimmsche Wörterbuch zitiert belege für "[stinkfaul](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB/?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GS47572)" seit dem 17. Jahrhundert und gibt dafür die Bedeutung

> so faul, dass er stinkt; stinkend faul

Bildungen wie "Stinkstiefel", "Stinkwut" und ähnliche sind moderne Bildungen vom Anfang des 20. Jahrhunderts*, in denen die Vorsilbe "stink-" als negative Verstärkung funktioniert.

Offenbar ist die Vorsilbe "stink-" also ursprünglich wörtlich gemeint, später verliert sie dann diese wörtliche Bedeutung und wirkt bloß verstärkend (wie "sau-" in "saukalt" oder "scheiß-" in "scheißegal" und viele andere ähnliche verstärkende Vorsilben mit fäkaler oder vulgärer wörtlicher Bedeutung).

**Wobei ältere Quellen immer schriftlich sind, so dass selten bekannt ist, wie lange bestimmte Begriffe vielleicht schon in der mündlichen Sprache exisitiert haben, bevor sie zum ersten Mal verschriftlicht wurden.*

Comment: Wobei Stiefel durchaus auch stinken können :-)

Answer (score 2):

Eine generelle Antwort kann ich nicht geben, für **stinkreich** jedoch kennen ich folgende Herkünfte (letztens gehört auf hr3, ebenfalls im [Redensarten-Index](http://www.redensarten-index.de/suche.php?suchbegriff=stinkreich%20&bool=relevanz&suchspalte%5B%5D=rart_ou) gefunden), beide gehen ins Mittelalter zurück:

- Damals galten Waidjunker durch Verarbeitung und Handel mit dem aus der [Färberwaid](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/F%C3%A4rberwaid) gewonnenen blauen Farbpulver als sehr reiche Leute. Damit der Pflanzenextrakt aber den richtigen Farbton erzeugte, musste er mit Urin angereichert werden. Diese Mischung fing während des Gärungsprozesses furchtbar an zu stinken. Zusätzlich waren diese Stoffe sehr teuer, so dass sie sich nur Reiche leisten konnten.
- Damals galt Fleisch als Delikatesse, welches sehr teuer war. Aufgrund mangelnder Mundhygiene fingen Reiche allerdings nach kurzer Zeit an, aus dem Mund zu stinken

Answer (score 1):

Da konstruiere ich doch mal eine eigene Erklärung:

Das Präfix(oid) "stink-" klingt sehr ähnlich wie das Präfix(oid) "stock-" und wird auch ähnlich gebraucht:

> stocksauer - stinksauer
>   stockbesoffen - stinkbesoffen

Beliebig kann man die beiden Präfixe allerdings nicht austauschen ("stockdunkel" aber nicht "stinkdunkel").

Doch ich vermute, dass "stink-" seinen Ursprung als Ersatz von "stock-" begonnen hat. Wenn jemand stockbesoffen ist, dann stinkt er auch ganz gern (nach Alkohol z.B.). So ist eine Zusammenführung naheliegend, denn:

> Du bist ja stinkbesoffen!

ist einfach kürzer als:

> Du bist ja stockbesoffen und stinkst (wie eine alkoholbedingte Blasenschwäche).

Wie es zum Präfixoid "stock-" kam, wird bei [gutefrage.de](http://www.gutefrage.net/frage/woher-kommt-die-redewendung-stock-besoffen-danke) näher erläutert.

Um zu zeigen, dass "stock" schon länger im Gebrauch ist als "stink", habe ich Dein [Ngramm](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=stinknormal,stinkreich,stinksauer,stockfinster,stockdumm&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=8&smoothing=3) erweitert.

Nein, Belege, dass meine Vermutung stimmt, habe ich keine.

Comment: Bei *stock-* kommt wohl eher die Bedeutung *"von Grund auf"* zum Tragen. Aber die Ähnlichkeit mit *"stink-"* ist auf jeden Fall (zumindest bei einem Teil der Adjektive) da.

Comment: @Takkat, von der früheren Bedeutung durchaus möglich (sie auch Stollen- und Baumstamm-Beispiel in meinem Link). Aber da sie ähnlich klingen, kann ich mir vorstellen, dass sich bei Gelegnheiten wie oben beschrieben der "Stink" eingschlichen hat.

Comment: Für die Herkunftserklärung von stock hättest du gar nicht fremdeln müssen, immerhin hat @Takkat diese ja auch schon von uns herausgekitzelt [What is the original meaning of the augmentative “stock-”?](http://german.stackexchange.com/q/3918/1224)

Comment: @Em1, entweder mein Gedächtnis ist noch schlechter als ich dachte (sprich: nicht vorhanden) oder die Frage ist mir durch die Lappen gegangen. Danke für den Link :)